# Extract Hours, minutes and seconds from Date format

Tags: jquery

I am using Ajax headers to get the current time, how can I retrieve just the hours, minutes and seconds and store them in their own variables from this string:

```
Wed, 15 May 2013 18:05:32 GMT
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Format it as a `Date` object, or use http://www.datejs.com/.

Comment: Try using regex expression \d:\d:\d and then split using ':' and then hours/minutes/seconds will be element 0, 1 and 2 respectively form the result of the split.

Comment: I punt this responsibility to http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Read date from header and pass that to Date object

```
var headerDate = "Wed, 15 May 2013 18:05:32 GMT";
    var date = new Date(headerDate );
    var hour = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var secs = date.getSeconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on @mclaassen 's answer:

```
//your date string
var dateStr  = 'Wed, 15 May 2013 18:05:32 GMT';
//regex patter to search on 
var patt  = /\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/;
//return the matching date string
var result = patt.exec(dateStr);

var hms = result.split(':');
//set individual variables
var hours = hms[0], min = hms[1], sec = hms [2];
```